# Javascript/Html: How to import local json / understanding module access

Tags: javascript, html, json, import, local

I am new to javascript / html and have some problems to understand the import / module functionality. I need to load a json file into javascript.

The best way I could find is via import, like:

```
  import myJason from './dummy.json' assert {type: 'json'};
```

When trying it, I am getting following error:

```
  Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

So I placed it into a module (tried header and body).
But I am not able to access the module functions.

Google could not help me, could please somebody explain how to do it properly.

**Note: HTML and JSON files are local files (not accessed via Webserver)**

Here is the (reduced) code:

```
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <script type="module">
                import myJason from './dummy.json' assert {type: 'json'};
                function dummy(){
                    //evaluate JSON
                    return result();
                }
                window.dummy = dummy;
                export{dummy}

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>


            <script>
                // tried (and other things)
                //   dummy();
                //  window.dummy();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: maybe look into loading JSON data in via "Ajax" - also, using `import` is part of something called Es6 with javascript which requires a compiler, you will need to use es5 syntax instead

Answer (score 1):

Try using XML HttpRequest

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function dummy(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       return JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
    }
}

xhttp.onreadystatechange = dummy
xhttp.open("GET", "/dummy.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

or even better the fetch api check that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_fetch.asp)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the HTML and JSON Files are local files (not accessed via Webserver). It seems that the provided solution do not work locally.

Comment: then check this [local file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)